# Split delimited 2nd and 3rd column data into new rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the following table

```
  ID.      ID2.              String
  123.     567, 986          ABC;BCD;ACD
  142.     134, 654,1134     AA;BB
```

I want it to be displayed

```
 ID   ID2  String
 123  567  ABC
 123  986  BCD
 123       ACD
 142  134  AA
 142  654  bb
 142  1134
```

The values in the `ID` column are unique.

Is there an efficient macro solution to this? I have a very huge set of data.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes specially if delimiter is fixed. Now for my question, what have you tried? In your attempt(s), what issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the starting, concatenated data in the active sheet and *ID* is in A1, run this macro.

```
Sub split_out()
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant, vID2s As Variant, vSTRs As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, mx As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=.Cells(lr + 2, 1)
        For rw = 2 To lr
            vVALs = Application.Index(.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value, 1, 0)
            vID2s = Split(vVALs(2), Chr(44))
            vSTRs = Split(vVALs(3), Chr(59))
            mx = Application.Max(UBound(vID2s), UBound(vSTRs))
            For v = LBound(vID2s) To mx
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = vVALs(1)
                If UBound(vID2s) >= v Then _
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = vID2s(v)
                If UBound(vSTRs) >= v Then _
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) = vSTRs(v)
            Next v
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

The flattened data will be populated below the existing data. Your results should be similar to the following.

[image: Flatten data with arrays]

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Sub FlattenData()
    Dim rng As Range, arr() As Variant, i As Long, rw As Long, j As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:C2") //Update for your range
    arr() = rng

    rng.ClearContents

            rw = 0

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        colBTemp = VBA.Split(arr(i, 2), ",")
        colCTemp = VBA.Split(arr(i, 3), ";")

        colBTempLength = UBound(colBTemp, 1) + 1
        colCTempLength = UBound(colCTemp, 1) + 1
        requiredRows = WorksheetFunction.Max(colBTempLength, colCTempLength)

        For j = 1 To requiredRows
            Range("A" & rw + j) = arr(i, 1)

            If j <= colBTempLength Then
                Range("B" & rw + j) = colBTemp(j - 1)
            Else
                Range("B" & rw + j) = vbNullString
            End If

            If j <= colCTempLength Then
                Range("C" & rw + j) = colCTemp(j - 1)
            Else
                Range("C" & rw + j) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next j

        rw = rw + requiredRows
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It clears all the contents and doesn't give me what I'm trying to get

Comment: As well as clearing the contents did anything get printed to the excel sheet? I tested it and seemed to work for me...

Comment: @AlexP - I thought that perhaps your `rng.ClearContents` should be moved below the `arr() = rng` code line.

Comment: I was trying to find the Cartesian product to result out all combinations from the above data set. Can you suggest some.changes to the above?

Comment: @user3317862 - Given that an answer has already been accepted I would raise a new question as what you are now aksing is different from the original request