# Duplicating line when cell has values separated by commas

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, flatten

I need to split each line into 2 WHEN there are values separated by commas in column 6 (over many lines).

Example (starting with 2 lines):

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G0 ,G1 
A* B* C* D* E* F* G0*,G1*
```

Is turned into:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G0
A  B  C  D  E  F  G1
A* B* C* D* E* F* G0*
A* B* C* D* E* F* G1*
```

Comment: this is a follow up on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674587/vba-error-not-enough-memory-for-the-operation

Comment: @ShaiRado I have adopted the answer marked correct, but the splitting is not being done. There you can see my initial code.

Comment: None of your examples in that question show a comma in column 6, nor what you want the result to look like should you have a comma. Again, post what you have tried to solve this question, and also examples of your data and desired output. But the `text to columns` wizard is one way to split this. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jony The reasons for the procedures are to enable you to ask a clear question, and receive useful information.   When you post questions that are not clear, more often than not, a lot of time is wasted as people try to interpret, often incorrectly, what it is you really want.  You might be better served by spending additional time in crafting good questions and providing good examples. Of course, you might get lucky and someone might hit on the right answer for you regardless!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm just really stressed, seeing that I'm not going to meet my deadline :(

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I don't know where else to turn to. I have little time and am not knowledgeable enough to do what I am/was supposed to do. Could you give me some "heavy" help? (Most of the project is already done, I just need to normalize the data and compare it to another sheet - and delete the line if the email is already in the other sheet)

Comment: This is my worst experience with vba, and my most needy moment in Stackoverflow. I don't know what else to do other than saying that I'm not able to cope with this myself and asking for stranger's kindness.

Comment: I also don't know how to initiate a chat, so, I hope the link will pop up here at any moment...

Comment: @jony  Jeeped's code will do exactly what you requested, once you get your references straightened out.  You need to think clearly about your entire project.  I don't have time this weekend to take on a "heavy" project.  But that is not generally the role of this site.

Comment: Yes, It did do it. And by "heavy" I didn't mean it would be a lot of work, more like me sharing the file, so that you could see exactly what was going on. Well, no matter what I meant, I am nearly done! And I'm feeling much more relieved thanks to you and the other incredible people on this site. Once again thanks for all your help in this moment of need. I'll be sure to share the little I know as much as possible. Maybe that will help clean my stackoverflow karma a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sup>Re-purposed [Split delimited 2nd and 3rd column data into new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856393/split-delimited-2nd-and-3rd-column-data-into-new-rows/29861673#29861673).</sup>

```
Option Explicit

Sub split_out()
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant, vSPLITs As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long, mx As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = lr To 2 Step -1
            vVALs = .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 7).Value2
            vSPLITs = Split(vVALs(1, 7), Chr(44))
            For v = UBound(vSPLITs) To LBound(vSPLITs) + 1 Step -1
                .Rows(rw + 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(1, 6) = _
                    Array(vVALs(1, 1), vVALs(1, 2), vVALs(1, 3), vVALs(1, 4), vVALs(1, 5), vVALs(1, 6))
                .Cells(rw + 1, 7) = Trim(vSPLITs(v))
            Next v
            .Cells(rw, 7) = Trim(vSPLITs(v))
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]
     From this...

[image]
     ... Into this.

Comment: I will humbly suggest that you stop what you are doing and go back over the examples provided to you in the last couple of hours. Go through thecode literally line-by-line  and if you do not understand anything, start with some research on your own. Running code that you do not understand is (quite simply) foolhardy.

Comment: ".Cells(rw, 7) = Trim(vSPLITs(v))"  this line is throwing a subscript out of range error

Comment: Probably nothing in column G for that row. Insert an if to make sure that v is >= zero.

Comment: I see what the problem was... it was not column g it was column F!

Comment: I changed all the references of row 7 to row 6. The extra data in the original lines is not getting deleted after the split

Comment: wait, it is the column 7 after all!

Comment: I'm going to take my dog to the park and throw a ball for an hour or two. You should consider doing the same; borrow a neighbour's dog if you do not have one yourself.

Comment: ok :( excuse my mess here today. Things are just going wrong with this project. I'm in over my head and hadn't realized until I saw how slow my code was. Thank you for your help (and for lending me what I don't seem to have?).

Comment: I got your script to work flawlessly. I understand it now. Thank you. And sorry for abusing your kindness. (This was/is just a crappy situation for me and next time I'll be better equipped to handle similar situations! Next time I'll have a little doggie of my own. For sure!)